# External WordPress API

Tags: api

I'd like to manipulate a WordPress website from another program/website. IS there an API already written that provides access, and authentication, to do this?

Ideally, I'll be using a multi-site wordpress instance and I want an outside program to add new sites, send config options to plugins, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Wordpress 4.7 (released December 2016), a REST API is provided out of the box on Wordpress.

As you're probably aware, REST APIs are interfaced with by standard HTTP GET and POST requests, so if you have a Wordpress 4.7 installation, you can access it at this URL, by plugging this into your browser:

http://your.site.com/wp/v2/posts

Further reading:

- [WP REST API, User Guide](http://v2.wp-api.org/)
- [WP REST API, Developer's Guide](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/)

---

**Important side note:**

Because this is turned on be default, because this exposes endpoints that can changes your data (via POST/PATCH/DELETE requests), and because Wordpress [prefers you not to disable it](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/frequently-asked-questions/#can-i-disable-the-rest-api), you really really ought to turn on some form of authentication. Thankfully, [turning on basic WP logged-in authentication](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/frequently-asked-questions/#require-authentication-for-all-requests) isn't particularly hard, and there are [plugins that will enable OAuth](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api-oauth1/).

Answer (score 4):

WordPpress platform provides [XML-RPC](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support) support which you can use to maintain your WP site. You also enable to **[extend](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Extending)** functionality of build in xml-rpc methods to use it for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple API plugins out there that work very well:

WP-API by Ryan McCue 
https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API

and JSON API by Dan Phiffer:
http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/